# stateProps value null in mergeProps

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have a `mapStateToProps` function that fires off an async request to fetch user data from the server.  The successful result of that, fires another action which actually sets the user to the state.  All of this works fine.  What I need to do now is, after the user data is set on the state, I need to fire another action (`setEditUserModel`) using the user value that was set from `fetchUser`.

Since `state` is not accessible in `mapStateToProps`, I've added the `mergeProps` connect option.  It's my understanding that this combines ("merges") the `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` together.  When I do this with the code below, `stateProps.user` in `mergeProps` is null even though the actual value when I inspect my AppState is not null.

```
function mapStateToProps(state: AppState): EditUserStateProps {
  return {
    user: state.user.data
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<ActionTypes>): EditUserDispatchProps {
  return {
    fetchUser: (id: number) => {
      return fetchUser(id)(dispatch);
    },
    setEditUserModel: (user: User) => {
      dispatch(actionCreators.setEditUserModel(user));
    }
  }
};

function mergeProps(stateProps: EditUserStateProps, dispatchProps: EditUserDispatchProps, ownProps: EditUserContainerProps) {
  return {
    ...ownProps,
    ...stateProps,
    ...dispatchProps,
    fetchUser: (id: number) => {
      return dispatchProps.fetchUser(id).then(() => {
        dispatchProps.setEditUserModel(stateProps.user);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Why is my `stateProps.user` value null?

Answer (score 0):

`stateProps.user` is null because of how javascript handles a closure's scope chain. When your closure that calls `dispatchProps.setEditUserModel()` gets executed after the `stateProps.fetchUser()` Promise is resolved, it is actually referencing the `stateProps` object that was within scope during its declaration, which happens to still contain a null `user` prop.

If you were to mutate the Redux store's state instead of copying it and then somehow pass that reference all the way down to your `mergeProps()`, you might see this bug disappear because now the `stateProps` in the `mergeProps()` closure references the same object that is in the redux store. However, this is not advisable because Redux reducers should be pure functions.

Instead, you might consider resolving the Promise returned in `stateProps.fetchUser()` with the `user` object and pass that to `dispatchProps.setEditUserModel()`.